# How to use non-String @RiakKey?

Tags: java, riak

Is it possible to use a field that isn't a String as a `@RiakKey`?  Here's what I have:

```
public class DomainObject {
  @RiakKey private UUID objectId;
}
```

Unfortunately, the current (v1.4.0) java client bombs out setting the key on deserialization:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.UUID field com.company.DomainObject.objectId to java.lang.String
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at com.basho.riak.client.convert.reflect.ClassUtil.setFieldValue(ClassUtil.java:45) ~[riak-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
at com.basho.riak.client.convert.reflect.AnnotationInfo.setRiakKey(AnnotationInfo.java:149) ~[riak-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
...snip
```

Is there any way to do this without degrading the domain object by changing the UUID to a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the default `JsonConverter` and annotation processing? No.

Keys is Riak are strings (ok, technically, some bytes ... but still certainly nothing that `UUID` object is going to automagically convert into).

The easiest way (and quite frankly, faster way given the overhead of reflection) is to write your own `Converter<T>` and use that instead of the default `JsonConverter`. You can either forego our annotation processing or use it for everything but the UUID.

It's fairly straight forward and obviously you can look at the source for `JsonConverter` on github[1] to see how it currently works. There's nothing very fancy there; there's some utility methods that do the annotation processing we use Jackson for the JSON conversion.

I also wrote a cookbook entry that covers writing and using a custom converter, it's in the wiki on github[2].

[1] https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/blob/1.4.1/src/main/java/com/basho/riak/client/convert/JSONConverter.java

[2] https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/wiki/Using-a-custom-Converter

**Edit to add:** <strike>The missing piece that really would solve your problem is if the `@RiakKey` annotation processing supported methods, which unfortunately it doesn't at the moment. It is something we're planning to add in the v2.0 rewrite of the client which we're currently working on.</strike>

**Updated 10/04/2013:** I needed to do a maintenance release for the 1.1.x and 1.4.x branches of the client, so I decided to add this as well. 1.1.3 and 1.4.2 will support getter/setter methods for `@RiakKey`. See: https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/pull/293

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - a custom converter did the trick!  I was surprised that @RiakKey wouldn't apply to methods; glad to hear that it's in the works.

Comment: @Ben - just as an FYI I've gone ahead and added this for 1.1.3 and 1.4.2 which I plan on releasing later today.